# Sharepoint Online (2013) Column Formatting Not Working

Tags: json, sharepoint, text, formatting

I have been testing the code located here...

[Github Repo ->](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-column-formatting/blob/master/samples/text-conditional-format/text-conditional-format.json)

...by creating a new field in my sharepoint list called "Test" and assigning either one of the original values (Done, In progress, In review, Has issues, Blocked) to each line item in the field. But copying over the code into the JSON input box does not work.

So I tried changing the "@currentField" to "@Test" or "Test" or "[$Test]" or "$Test" and none of those worked either.

Can someone help me get this working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggled with this, also.  I finally got it to work after I did the following:

1. Changed List Settings -> Advanced settings -> List experience to
   'New experience'... I don't know if it works in 'Default experience set by my 
   administrator' or 'Classic experience'.
2. Created a new List View... the column customizations didn't
   show up in the default 'All Items' view.

Comment: Yeah, a coworker just told me this worked for him today. Thank you for the response @Stormy ! Unfortunately the new list experience does not have all the functionality of the original I guess. That's next for me to investigate.

Comment: @J.Knapp Did you work out a way to keep the old experience while using this new JSON functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that may be related. I found that if I refer to another column in the JSON (e.g. [$Other_x0020_Column]) and also have that column appearing in the view then it did not render.

The solution for me was to only show the fields in he custom formatted result and untick it from the remainder of the display.

NB: This was an observation in one location, I have not thoroughly tested this elsewhere